# recursion square root, tolerance is .1 off

Tags: java, recursion

I am calculating the square root using recursion, and I can't seem to figure out why `tol` is coming up `.1` short.

```
public static float sqrRootRec(float number, float approx, float tol) {

    if((Math.abs((Math.pow(approx,2) - number))<= tol*number)) {
       return approx;
    } else
       return sqrRootRec(number, (approx*approx + number)/(approx + approx),tol);
}
```

Comment: go back and give  points to the people who helped - otherwise no help here

Comment: I couldn't upvote gpasch's comment twice, so here's a comment. Don't abuse the site. You have many questions with no accepted answers, albiet thr answers are fine. Please show some respect to the people who invested their time into helping you.

Comment: @gpasch I did click the up arrow for both of them, I also said thanks.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I am new to this site. I upvoted both of them as they gave me help, but it said I need 15 reputation points before it will show up. I didn't know how to reply with another question to them so I made a new topic.
I am sorry.

Comment: It is true. You cannot up vote now but you can accept the correct answer

Comment: @GWS [Here is the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [here is the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Welcome to the site :) After looking into those, I suggest going back and giving reputation to the people who have helped you by accepting their answers

Comment: @VinceEmigh I didn't even realize what the check mark did.. I am a first year CIS major and I am having tons and tons of trouble with my professors as I can't understand them, they are foreign. I know that I am not the only one in the class that is like myself, that's just why I'm trying to get help here because it's quick and people seem to go into depth on why things are happening the way they are.

Comment: @GWS It's best to inform your professors that you are confused. It's their job to make sure you are on the same page as them. If you come here for help, nothing will prevent you from misunderstanding the next lesson